# Rails 3 - acts_as_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I install "acts_as_nested_set" in my Rails 3 app?

I want to be able to add acts_as_nested_set to my model

I also want to be able to use ROOT, like this...

```
article.comments.roots.order
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Awesome Nested Set](http://github.com/galetahub/awesome_nested_set) (at least some of its forks) and [Nested Set](http://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) on github. They provide acts_as_nested_set replacement for Rails 3.